# How to push two array values on the same index?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm working with React Leaflet and I need to pass some values to draw a Polyline, this is how the value I need to pass.

```
const polyline = [
  [51.505, -0.09],
  [51.51, -0.1],
  [51.51, -100.12],
]
```

So far this is the function that I wrote to pass the values

```
    const drawLine = () => {
        for(var i=0; i<points.length; i++) {
            track.push([points[i].latitude],[points[i].longitude]);
        }
        console.log(track);
    }
```

But the output is not as I expected and it looks something like this.

```
0: Array(1)
0: [19.574815]
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

So my question is, how to succeed on making the array that I need with the two values that I already got look like that **polyline** array that [React Leaflet uses on their page](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-vector-layers/)?

Answer (score 2):

You're passing two arguments to `.push`, not one.

```
track.push([points[i].latitude],[points[i].longitude]);
```

is equivalent to doing

```
track.push([points[i].latitude]);
track.push([points[i].longitude]);
```

Change to

```
track.push([
  points[i].latitude,
  points[i].longitude
]);
```

In case `track` is empty beforehand, it'd be even more elegant to use `.map`.

```
const track = points.map(point => [
  point.latitude,
  point.longitude
]);
```